# Django How to get a queryset from another queryset in a template

Tags: python, html, django, django-queryset

I want to filter a queryset that depends on another queryset that already depends on another queryset

My models.py

```
class Escola(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField(db_column='Nome', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Inscrio(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    escolaid = models.ForeignKey(Escola, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='EscolaID', blank=True, null=True)

class Utilizador(AbstractBaseUser)
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    inscriçãoid = models.ForeignKey(Inscrio, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='InscriçãoID', blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(db_column='Email', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True) 
    nome = models.CharField(db_column='Nome', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(db_column='Password', max_length=500, default='pass');

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
```

My views.py

```
def view_forms(request):
   return render(request, 
                 "main/view_forms.html", 
                 {"escolas": Escola.objects.all(),
                 })
```

I am doing

```
{% for escola in escolas %}
   {% for inscrio in escola.inscrio_set.all %}
        {% for utilizador in inscrio.utilizador_set.all %}
            <tr>
            <td><center>{{inscrio.id}}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{escola.nome}}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{utilizador.id}}</center></td> 
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am currently trying to get the Inscrio data from Escola.
But when I try to get the Utlizador data from the Inscrio I get nothing.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you want, I think you are going about this backwards. Try this:

views.py:

```
def view_forms(request):
   return render(request, 
                 "main/view_forms.html", 
                 {"utilizadores": Utilizador.objects.all().order_by('inscriçãoid__escolaid__id'),
                 })
```

In your template:

```
{% for utilizador in utilizadores %}
        <tr>
        <td><center>{{utilizador.inscriçãoid.id}}</center></td>
        <td><center>{{utilizador.inscriçãoid.escolaid.nome}}</center></td>
        <td><center>{{utilizador.id}}</center></td> 
    {% endfor %}
```

I will update my answer if this isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: thats only printing the last one ("{{utilizador.id}}"). doesnt print the other ones

Comment: Make sure the data in your database has those foreign key fields populated. As shown, it should print all of the data if it is present. I noticed you allow them to be blank and null.

Comment: yep, I am sure they are populated

Comment: You have it in your template EXACTLY as above?

Comment: Can you print the contents of the "utilizadores" object from my code in your console and show me what it looks like?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Create an object like: u = Utilizador.objects.all() then print to the console: print(u.values(), file=sys.stdout) - make sure to import sys to do that part

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is the worst way to do that. You're trying to render a table with utilizador's information from all escolas, so get it all and render it!. You can order it by escola id maybe.

```
query = Utilizador.objects.all().order_by('inscriçãoid__escolaid__id')

template
{% for q in query %}
    <tr>
    <td><center>{{q.inscriçãoid.id}}</center></td>
    <td><center>{{q.inscriçãoid.escola.nome}}</center></td>
    <td><center>{{q.id}}</center></td> 
{% endfor %}
```